# Understanding the bootstrapped method for calculating non-parametric p-values

Tags: p-value, nonparametric, bootstrap

I'm trying to understand the non-parametric bootstrapping to calculate p-values.  I understand pearson correlation has it's own method for calculating p-values but I'm just using this as an example.

My understanding of the process is the following (for a two-sided test calculating p-value for vectors X and Y):

1. Calculate the metric using all the data (e.g., pearson's coefficient)
2. Set the number of bootstraps you want (e.g., N=10,000)
3. Hold one vector constant, the other permute the labels with replacement
4. Calculate the metric using the permuted data and store that info
5. Repeat steps 3-4 N times
6. Count the number of times the absolute value of the bootstrapped values are greater than the absolute value of the observed value (e.g., number_of_extreme_values)
7. Divide number_of_extreme_values by N to get a bootstrapped p-value.

In the case of something like Euclidean distance, you would do a 1-sided test to see if the bootstrapped value is lower than the observed value for steps 6-7.

**Does this make sense or is my logic flawed?**

Here's some example code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# Simulated data (replace with your own data)
number_of_samples = 100
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, number_of_samples)
Y = 2 * X + np.random.normal(0, 10, number_of_samples)

# Observed correlation
observed_corr, observed_pvalue = stats.pearsonr(X,Y)

# Number of bootstrap resampling iterations
n_iter = 10000

bootstrapped_correlations = list()
for i in tqdm(range(n_iter)):
    Y_resampled = np.random.RandomState(i).choice(Y, size=Y.size, 
                                                  replace=True)
    query_corr = stats.pearsonr(X, Y_resampled)[0]
    bootstrapped_correlations.append(query_corr)
    
number_of_extreme_values = np.sum(np.abs(bootstrapped_correlations) >= 
       np.abs(observed_corr))
bootstrapped_pvalue = number_of_extreme_values/N
observed_corr, observed_pvalue, bootstrapped_pvalue
# (0.29477619864462, 0.002909408566197212, 0.16)
```